# PhantomJS render PDF result is huge > 25mb. Print from web < 1mb. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: pdf, printing, phantomjs, render

We are converting from an old site built in PHP/jQuery to Angular JS. We are using PhantomJS to render reports as pdfs. The old site does this fine and all reports are under 2 mb. The new site renders the reports 10 times as large. When I print pdf from Chrome, the result is under a meg. We've tried using ghostscript to compress the result, but it barely shaves a tenth off. When looking at the large resultant pdf in Acrobat, everything is an image, which explains the size. The problem is, I have no clue why everything is rendering as images. I'm completely baffled.

Answer (score 0):

While I hope you can find a quick solution (eg, try changing the PhantomJS virtual screen size), another option is to build the pdf more directly, such as with [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) (free, lots of docs). Then you can control the pdf more directly, and don't need PhantomJS.

It seems the issue is with PhantomJS 2, which goes off the DPI setting of the server.  You could try an older PhantomJS (did you change servers?).  Or try this:

```
page.dpi = 96.0;
```

and experiment with different min width sizes on your report

```
 { min-width: 1200px; }
```

follow this issue for updates:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12685

Comment: *"try changing the PhantomJS virtual screen size"* how would you go about doing that?

Comment: @ArtjomB. looks like you're not alone.  see edited post and link

Comment: I would love to go with a solution to build the pdf more specifically, but that would be a huge undertaking. The real question at hand is: why is PhantomJS rendering the images instead of text?

Comment: @jbaddley have you changed any css?  maybe some css3 can't be rendered by pdf  to it turns it to a image.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing yes, a lot of css has been changed. I'm just wondering what css could possibly be doing that. I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: @jbaddley well I suggest removing all the css to just see if renders as text.  It could be anything, a box shadow, a google font...